# how to apply ceiling to pandas DateTime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with a column whose values are `datetime64[ns]`.

```
Out[204]: 
0   2015-03-20 00:00:28
1   2015-03-20 00:01:44
2   2015-03-20 00:02:55
3   2015-03-20 00:03:39
4   2015-03-20 00:04:32
5   2015-03-20 00:05:52
6   2015-03-20 00:06:36
7   2015-03-20 00:07:44
8   2015-03-20 00:08:56
9   2015-03-20 00:09:47
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Is there any easy way to convert them the nearest minute after the time? i.e. I want the following:

```
Out[204]: 
0   2015-03-20 00:01:00
1   2015-03-20 00:02:00
2   2015-03-20 00:03:00
3   2015-03-20 00:04:00
4   2015-03-20 00:05:00
5   2015-03-20 00:06:00
6   2015-03-20 00:07:00
7   2015-03-20 00:08:00
8   2015-03-20 00:09:00
9   2015-03-20 00:10:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I wrote a complicate code that first converts them to string and then extracts the three portions of `00:09:47`, convert them into integers, then unless the last portion (seconds) is already `00`, I make the last portion (seconds) to be `00`, adds `1` to the middle portion (minutes) except if the middle portion (minutes) is already `59` in which case it adds to the first portion (hours). Then recombine the new integers back to a string and then reconstruct back the `DateTime`.

But I was thinking that may there might be already an existing simpler solution. Would anyone have any suggestions?

*** EDIT ***

@Jeff, @unutbu, thanks for your answers. I can only select one answer in SO, but both work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a DataFrame with a column of dtype `datetime64[ns]`, you could 
use

```
df['date'] += np.array(-df['date'].dt.second % 60, dtype='<m8[s]')
```

to add the appropriate number of seconds to obtain the ceiling.

---

For example,

```
import io
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
StringIO = io.BytesIO if sys.version < '3' else io.StringIO

df = '''\
2015-03-20 00:00:00
2015-03-20 00:00:28
2015-03-20 00:01:44
2015-03-20 00:02:55
2015-03-20 00:03:39
2015-03-20 00:04:32
2015-03-20 00:05:52
2015-03-20 00:06:36
2015-03-20 00:07:44
2015-03-20 00:08:56
2015-03-20 00:09:47'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(df), sep='\s{2,}', 
                   header=None, parse_dates=[0], names=['date'])

df['date'] += np.array(-df['date'].dt.second % 60, dtype='<m8[s]')
print(df)
```

yields

```
                  date
0  2015-03-20 00:00:00
1  2015-03-20 00:01:00
2  2015-03-20 00:02:00
3  2015-03-20 00:03:00
4  2015-03-20 00:04:00
5  2015-03-20 00:05:00
6  2015-03-20 00:06:00
7  2015-03-20 00:07:00
8  2015-03-20 00:08:00
9  2015-03-20 00:09:00
10 2015-03-20 00:10:00
```

Comment: Umm.... I was reading the question that if the seconds are 0 - then the minute shouldn't roll forward...

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks for point this out. I've added a correction.

Comment: Don't take my word for it though... that's just the way I've interpreted the OP's description!

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct since the OP does call it a "ceiling" and mentions special-casing "unless the last portion (seconds) is already 00".

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way. Subtract off the differential seconds (sort of like round). This is vectorized.

```
In [46]: df.date+pd.to_timedelta(-df.date.dt.second % 60,unit='s')
Out[46]: 
0   2015-03-20 00:01:00
1   2015-03-20 00:02:00
2   2015-03-20 00:03:00
3   2015-03-20 00:04:00
4   2015-03-20 00:05:00
5   2015-03-20 00:06:00
6   2015-03-20 00:07:00
7   2015-03-20 00:08:00
8   2015-03-20 00:09:00
9   2015-03-20 00:10:00
dtype: datetime64[ns
```

Here's another way. Changing something to a Period of another frequency rounds it. (Note that this is a bit clunky ATM because Periods are not full-fledged as a column type). This is vectorized.

```
In [48]: pd.Series(pd.PeriodIndex(df.date.dt.to_period('T')+1).to_timestamp())
Out[48]: 
0   2015-03-20 00:01:00
1   2015-03-20 00:02:00
2   2015-03-20 00:03:00
3   2015-03-20 00:04:00
4   2015-03-20 00:05:00
5   2015-03-20 00:06:00
6   2015-03-20 00:07:00
7   2015-03-20 00:08:00
8   2015-03-20 00:09:00
9   2015-03-20 00:10:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This last method will always round 'up' as we are incrementing the floored period.

Comment: Nice! Also, `df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(-df['date'].dt.second % 60, unit='s')` will leave dates with zero seconds unchanged.

Comment: @unutbu jeeze - why didn't we think of that one to start with :p (think that's the reason for love/hate relation with `pandas` - seems obvious when you know the answer... but neither of us initially took that approach!)

Comment: I'm like a democracy -- I try every possible wrong answer until I find the right one :)

Answer (score 3):

Now a built-in method `ceil()` is available in pandas for this. For a Series of datetime it can be accessed using `Series.dt.ceil()`:

```
In[92]: t
Out[92]: 
0   2015-03-20 00:00:28
1   2015-03-20 00:01:44
2   2015-03-20 00:02:55
3   2015-03-20 00:03:39
4   2015-03-20 00:04:32
5   2015-03-20 00:05:52
6   2015-03-20 00:06:36
7   2015-03-20 00:07:44
8   2015-03-20 00:08:56
9   2015-03-20 00:09:47
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In[93]: t.dt.ceil('min')
Out[93]: 
0   2015-03-20 00:01:00
1   2015-03-20 00:02:00
2   2015-03-20 00:03:00
3   2015-03-20 00:04:00
4   2015-03-20 00:05:00
5   2015-03-20 00:06:00
6   2015-03-20 00:07:00
7   2015-03-20 00:08:00
8   2015-03-20 00:09:00
9   2015-03-20 00:10:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

`ceil()` accepts frequency parameter. String aliases for it are listed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

Comment: Tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016264/how-to-create-a-column-of-ceil-dates-in-pandas based on your suggestion, but got an "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" error.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might need a little bit of work, but I think this is roughly what you're after (I'm sure there's a way to use `.snap` or an offsets `.rollforward`, but can't seem to get those to work):

```
ps = pd.Series([
        datetime(2015, 1, 1, 19, 18, 34), # roll up min, reset sec
        datetime(2015, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), # roll up min, reset sec
        datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), # do nothing
        datetime(2015, 1, 1, 23, 59, 1), # roll day/hr/min, reset sec
        datetime(2015, 1, 31, 23, 59, 1), # roll mth/day/hr/min, reset sec
        datetime(2015, 12, 31, 23, 59, 1) # roll yr/month/day/hr/min - reset sec
    ])
ps[ps.dt.second != 0] = ps.apply(lambda L: (L + timedelta(minutes=1)).replace(second=0))
```

Which gives you:

```
0   2015-01-01 19:19:00
1   2015-01-01 01:02:00
2   2015-01-01 00:00:00
3   2015-01-02 00:00:00
4   2015-02-01 00:00:00
5   2016-01-01 00:00:00
```