# How to create a column of ceil dates in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a column that is the end-of-the-month date to a pandas dataframe.  Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177656/how-to-apply-ceiling-to-pandas-datetime#39306166), I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2014-06-02', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-04', '2014-06-05', '2014-06-06']
sp500_index = [1924.969971, 1924.23999, 1927.880005, 1940.459961, 1949.439941]
df_sp500 = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : dates, 'Close' : sp500_index})
sp500['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sp500['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_sp500['EOM'] = df_sp500['Date'].dt.ceil('M')  # breaks on this line
#df_sp500 = df_sp500[df_sp500['Date'] == df_sp500['EOM']]

df_sp500
```

but I get this error message:

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

The reason I want to add this column is to use it to filter out all but the EOM dates as shown in the commented out line.

Comment: You have `df_sp500 =` and `sp500['Date'] =`.  Which is it?

Comment: Very new to pandas (coming from R).  Intention was `df_sp500 =` to create the dataframe and the `sp500['Date'] =` line to convert the `Date` field from a string to Datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already built-in to `datetime` with [`pandas.Series.is_month_end`](http://nipy.bic.berkeley.edu/nightly/pandas/doc/generated/pandas.Series.is_month_end.html). Instead of calculating a new column just subset with:

```
df_sp500[df_sp500.Date.dt.is_month_end]
```

#### Input Data

```
dates = ['2014-06-02', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-04', '2014-06-05', '2014-06-06']
sp500_index = [1924.969971, 1924.23999, 1927.880005, 1940.459961, 1949.439941]

df_sp500 = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : dates, 'Close' : sp500_index})
df_sp500['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sp500['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd


dates = ['2014-06-02', '2014-06-03', '2014-06-04', '2014-06-05', '2014-06-06']
sp500_index = [1924.969971, 1924.23999, 1927.880005, 1940.459961, 1949.439941]
df_sp500 = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : dates, 'Close' : sp500_index})
df_sp500['EOM'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sp500['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')+ MonthEnd(0)
#df_sp500['EOM']=df_sp500['EOM'].dt.day #add this if you want only day
```

Comment: The @ALollz answer was exactly what I was looking for, but thank you for this great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the document

> The frequency level to ceil the index to. Must be a fixed frequency
>   like ‘S’ (second) not ‘ME’ (month end)

So we may using `MonthBegin` for your case

```
df_sp500['Date']- pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1) #pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
0   2014-06-01
1   2014-06-01
2   2014-06-01
3   2014-06-01
4   2014-06-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```